# storing values from loop

Tags: python, arrays

For example I have this code:

```
for r in res:
    for x,y in r:
        print(x,y)
```

And the output is this:

```
[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1] (0.3779644730092272, 1)
[1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] (0.4472135954999579, 0)
[0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1] (0.4472135954999579, 1)
```

But how do I store the first column which is the 0's and 1's in a single variable like this:

```
[[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1]
[1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

I also tried this:

```
for r in res:
    for x,y in r:
        first = x
```

But this only stores the last value. Is there a neat way or a one liner in python that can do this?

Answer (score 4):

That looks like a straight list comprehension:

```
result = [x for r in res for x,y in r]
```

You seem to be working with 2D arrays of numbers - you might consider using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) here.

Comment: Another top notch answer @wim!